# Algorithm finding path with maximal ratio of white vertices

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

Recently I encountered an interesting graph problem and couldn't find proper solution: given undirected graph `G = <V, E>`, each vertex is either white or black. You need to find the path between given vertices `s` and `t` such that if `W` is the number of white vertices on that path and `L` is the length of the path, `W/L` is maximal possible. Obviously, the faster the algorithm is, the better.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is NP-hard, by the following reduction from the Longest Path Problem:

Color every vertex white but s and t. Then any s-t-path with W white vertices has length W+1, so it maximizes W/L = W/(W+1) if and only if it is a longest s-t-path.